# kubernetes nginx ingress controller disable HTTP 200 log

Tags: logging, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

is there any way to disable the HTTP 200 logging at the nginx ingress controller? It takes too much disk space and this requires a lot of maintenance.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in here https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/troubleshooting/#debug-logging

log-level can be configured in the deployment by using the flag `--v=X` try with the levels `--v=0`, `--v=1`, `--v=2`... and use which makes sense to you.

Comment: I tried all `v` options, but couldn't find any one that disables the logging, even logging less.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with ingress-nginx out of the box unfortunately. But see https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3245 for some workarounds.